# How to make MATLAB return char instead of ASCII?

Tags: matlab, encoding, ascii

So, I'm using AT Commands with Matlab to return the Caller ID, but this doesn't really matter.

Everything is working great except for the fact that it returns ASCII numbers and I have to take my time "translating" that ASCII code to char so I can know what is it saying.

```
>> s = serial('COM8');
>> fopen(s)
>> fwrite(s, [65 84 43 67 82 67 61 49 13])
>> s

   Serial Port Object : Serial-COM8

   Communication Settings 
      Port:               COM8
      BaudRate:           9600
      Terminator:         'LF'

   Communication State 
      Status:             open
      RecordStatus:       off

   Read/Write State  
      TransferStatus:     idle
      BytesAvailable:     47
      ValuesReceived:     0
      ValuesSent:         18

>> fread(s, 47)
```

It returns me 47 ASCII numbers like this(note that I have deleted most of the returned code):

```
ans =

    65
    84
    43
    67
    82
    67
    61
    49
    13
```

I've tried the following things:

```
char(fread(s,47))
```

and

```
z = fread(s,47)
char(z)
```

but neither of those worked, however

```
z = [65 84 43 67 82 67 61 49 13]
char(z)
```

works fine. I suppose it is because `fread` returns the ASCII code with newline between them and not just space like I wrote in the code above.

Comment: What is the result when you run `class(fread(s,47))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used class(s) to find out that the returned class is `serial`. So I found out about `fgets` and it worked great.More info about fgets on http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fgets.html

Here is the input/output.

```
tline = fgets(s)
tline =
ATD0888123456
```

Answer (score 1):

try `str2double`, `str2num` or just subtract `'0'` ( the ascii value of the char '0' ) from the ascii code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it when reading from a file --

```
>> s = fopen('.gitignore') # Just a file in my current directory
>> z = fread(s,10)         # Returns a column of numbers
z =
    43
    97
    114
    98
   105
   116
   114
    97
   114
   121
>> char(transpose(z))      # You could write z' instead of transpose(z)
ans =
+arbitrary
```

Where "+arbitrary" are the first 10 characters of the file I read.